# Change the font used by XTerm for its menus

Tags: xterm

[image]

Here I am, using a  185 dpi display, and the font of XTerm menus¹ borders the unreadable small.

Investigating XTerm's XResources, I found a promising name but

```
$ xrdb -merge
XTerm*SimpleMenu*menuLabel.font: -*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-180-100-100-*-*-iso10646-1^D
$
```

didn't help.

Is it possible to specify a larger font for XTerm's menus?

---

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wiodj.png) The fonts of the VT100 widget(?) are perfectly fine, this is not a question about changing the fonts of the XTerm main window.

Comment: Ahh those menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be less specific, and it should work:

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm*SimpleMenu*font: -*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-180-100-*-*-*-*-*'
```

(You seem to have an extra `^D` at the end of your example).
Make sure you have the font, test with

```
xlsfonts -fn '-*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-180-100-*-*-*-*-*'
```

and find one with `xfontsel`.

Comment: The `^d` is an overzealous attempt to represent an EoF passed to `xrdb`. It seems that an even more generic `XTerm*font: ...` would do, and I was posting it as an answer but you have been faster! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (even more) generic font specification

```
$ xrdb -merge
XTerm*font: -*-helvetica-medium-r-*-*-*-140-100-100-*-*-iso10646-1
$ xterm
```

and here it is what a XTerm's menu now looks like.
[image]